# How to stop scrolling with an overlay modal?

Tags: jquery, css, locomotive-scroll

I started using locomotive and made an overlay menu.
Normally I should have use an overflow hidden. But here it's not working

```
.scroll-stop
{
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
    $('body').toggleClass('scroll-stop');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stop() and start() methods to disable and enable scrolling.
https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll#instance-methods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).